# No constructor for type 'MyProject.Response' can be instantiated using services from the service container and default values

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, c#-8.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using asp.net core 3.1 project template to develop a web API. There are no compilation errors.

Here goes my code details:

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Use the W3C Trace Context format to propagate distributed trace identifiers.
        // See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/improvements-in-net-core-3-0-for-troubleshooting-and-monitoring-distributed-apps/
        Activity.DefaultIdFormat = ActivityIdFormat.W3C;
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref = "Startup"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "configuration">The application configuration, where key value pair settings are stored. See
    /// http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html</param>
    /// <param name = "webHostEnvironment">The environment the application is running under. This can be Development,
    /// Staging or Production by default. See http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html</param>
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures the services to add to the ASP.NET Core Injection of Control (IoC) container. This method gets
    /// called by the ASP.NET runtime. See
    /// http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext.aspx
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) => 
        services
        .AddCosmosDBConfiguration(configuration)
        .AddAutoMapperConfiguration()
        .AddCustomResponseCompression(configuration)
        .AddCustomCors()
        .AddCustomOptions(configuration)
        .AddHttpContextAccessor()
        .AddCustomRouting()
        .AddCustomStrictTransportSecurity()
        .AddCustomHealthChecks()
        .AddServerTiming()
        .AddControllers()
           .AddCustomJsonOptions(webHostEnvironment)
           .AddCustomMvcOptions(configuration)
        .Services
        .AddCustomGraphQL(configuration, webHostEnvironment)
        .AddGraphQLResolvers()
        .AddGraphQLResponse()
        .AddProjectRepositories()
        .AddProjectSchemas();

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures the application and HTTP request pipeline. Configure is called after ConfigureServices is
    /// called by the ASP.NET runtime.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application) =>
        application
            .UseIf(
                this.webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment(),
                x => x.UseServerTiming())
        .UseForwardedHeaders()
        .UseResponseCompression()
        .UseFetchLocaleMiddleware()
        .UseIf(
                !this.webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment(),
                x => x.UseHsts())
            .UseIf(
                this.webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment(),
                x => x.UseDeveloperExceptionPage())
        .UseRouting()
            .UseCors(CorsPolicyName.AllowAny)
        .UseEndpoints(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .MapHealthChecks("/status")
                        .RequireCors(CorsPolicyName.AllowAny);
                    builder
                        .MapHealthChecks("/status/self", new HealthCheckOptions() { Predicate = _ => false })
                        .RequireCors(CorsPolicyName.AllowAny);
                })
        .UseWebSockets()
            // Use the GraphQL subscriptions in the specified schema and make them available at /graphql.
            .UseGraphQLWebSockets<MainSchema>()
            // Use the specified GraphQL schema and make them available at /graphql.
            .UseGraphQL<MainSchema>()
            .UseIf(
                this.webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment(),
                x => x
                    // Add the GraphQL Playground UI to try out the GraphQL API at /.
                    .UseGraphQLPlayground(new GraphQLPlaygroundOptions() { Path = "/" })
                    // Add the GraphQL Voyager UI to let you navigate your GraphQL API as a spider graph at /voyager.
                    .UseGraphQLVoyager(new GraphQLVoyagerOptions() { Path = "/voyager" }));
}
```

**Response.cs**

```
public class Response
{
    public object Data { get; set; }

    public string StatusCode { get; set; }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public Response(object data)
    {
        StatusCode = "Success";
        Data = data;
    }

    public Response(string statusCode, string errorMessage)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

All the dependencies mentioned in the `ConfigureServices` of the Startup.cs are available. While validating the APIs I am getting a run time error as mentioned below:

> No constructor for type 'MyProject.Response' can be instantiated using services from the service container and default values.

Here goes the dependency setup required for the Response class as mentioned below:

**ProjectServiceCollectionExtensions.cs**

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public static class ProjectServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddGraphQLResponse(this IServiceCollection services) => services.AddScoped<Response>();
    }
}
```

**Resolver.cs**

```
public class Resolver
{
    public Response Response(object data)
    {
        return new Response(data);
    }

    public Response Error(GraphQLError error)
    {
        return new Response(error.StatusCode, error.ErrorMessage);
    }

    public Response AccessDeniedError()
    {
        var error = new AccessDeniedError();
        return new Response(error.StatusCode, error.ErrorMessage);
    }

    public Response NotFoundError(string id)
    {
        var error = new NotFoundError(id);
        return new Response(error.StatusCode, error.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

**CountriesResolver.cs**

```
using Author.Core.Framework.Utilities;
using Author.Query.New.API.GraphQL.Types;
using Author.Query.Persistence.DTO;
using Author.Query.Persistence.Interfaces;
using GraphQL.DataLoader;
using GraphQL.Types;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;

namespace MyProject.GraphQL.Resolvers
{
    public class CountriesResolver : Resolver, ICountriesResolver
    {
        private readonly ICountryService _countryService;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
        private readonly IUtilityService _utilityService;
        private readonly IDataLoaderContextAccessor _dataLoaderContextAccessor;
        public CountriesResolver(ICountryService countryService, IHttpContextAccessor accessor, IUtilityService utilityService, IDataLoaderContextAccessor dataLoaderContextAccessor)
        {
            _countryService = countryService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(countryService));
            _accessor = accessor;
            _utilityService = utilityService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(utilityService));
            _dataLoaderContextAccessor = dataLoaderContextAccessor;
        }

        public void Resolve(GraphQLQuery graphQLQuery)
        {
            var language = _accessor.HttpContext.Items["language"] as LanguageDTO;
            graphQLQuery.FieldAsync<ResponseGraphType<CountryResultType>>("countriesresponse", resolve: async context =>
            {
                if (language != null)
                {
                    var loader = _dataLoaderContextAccessor.Context.GetOrAddLoader("GetAllCountries", () => _countryService.GetAllCountriesAsync(language));
                    var list = await context.TryAsyncResolve(async c => await loader.LoadAsync());
                    return Response(list);
                }

                return null;
            }

            , description: "All Countries data");
            graphQLQuery.FieldAsync<ResponseGraphType<CountryType>>("country", arguments: new QueryArguments(new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<IntGraphType>>{Name = "countryId", Description = "id of the country"}), resolve: async context =>
            {
                var countryId = context.GetArgument<int>("countryId");
                if (language != null && countryId > 0)
                {
                    var loader = _dataLoaderContextAccessor.Context.GetOrAddLoader("GetCountry", () => _countryService.GetCountryAsync(language, countryId));
                    var countryDetails = await context.TryAsyncResolve(async c => await loader.LoadAsync());
                    return Response(countryDetails);
                }

                return null;
            }

            );
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue by providing their guidance

Comment: Just throwing in a 2c, but what happens if you add a public parameterless contructor in Response?

Comment: Thanks @npinti for your response.I tried your suggestion but it is not working.The same setup works fine in case of asp.net core 2.2

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro I find it hard to believe that setup worked in the previous version. How is the container  suppose to know which constructor to select and what values to provide? Can you show an example of how and where that class is used?

Comment: @Nkosi : Thanks for your response. I have updated the code with the usage of Response.cs. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro If the response object is being created manually within Resolver, why is it even being added to the container? And is Resolver used by the container? If `Response` is not explicitly injected anywhere then the container does not need to be aware of it. No need to add it to begin with.

Comment: How is resolver used?

Comment: I have updated the code now containing the usage of Resolver.cs

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro Ok based on how `Response` is used by `Resolver` I would say `Response` does not need to be added to the DI/IoC container. Since `Resolver` is essentially  a `Response` factory

Comment: Why are you registering Response as a service to the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on how `Response` is used by `Resolver` I would say `Response` does not need to be added to the DI/IoC container, since `Resolver` is essentially  a `Response` factory

If `Response` is not explicitly injected anywhere then the container does not need to be aware of it. No need to add it to the container begin with.

Remove

```
//...
.AddGraphQLResponse() //<--SHOULD BE REMOVED
//...
```

extension from `Startup.ConfigureServices`

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi for your response. It helped me to fix the issue :).